# I have a span text. I want the same text to change into submit button

Tags: jsp

I have 4 jsp pages with common header for all of them (something like Page1 Page2 Page3 Page4).
When I am on Page2, Page2 part of the header is highlighted.
As the text Page1, Page2 etc are all spans, they are simple texts.

Now I want to convert the header spans (say Page1, when I am on Page2) to submitt button (without changing the way they look), so that I can click on Page1 (or any Page1,2,3 etc) and move to the respective Page.

Code for the header is something like:

```
<li class="past"><span class="lebel">Page1</span></li>
<li class="present"><strong><span class="lebel">Page2</span></strong></li>
<li class="future"><span class="lebel">Page3</span></li>
<li class="future"><span class="lebel">Page4</span></li>
```

Please suggest how to inject

Comment: usually these are hyper links

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onclick="goToPage(1)"`, probably needing a cursor setting and hoovering `class="... linked"`. And in javascript `function goToPage(p)` set an input hidden pageno, and submit the form.

You might also consider jsp tags, JSF, maybe even some page navigation component.

Comment: I added the javascript function call onClick. Doing only this doesn't help. I don't know about cursor setting & hoovering and how this can help me achieve my goal. :(

Comment: The class meant to style the text as clickable, as a link. So not needed in the first stage. As @Dunken said, often every page is a link to some URL. Your question suggested you have a form. Can you show the HTML a bit?

Comment: I cannot use a hyperlink as the submitt button doesnot redirect it directly to any link (complete url), It just attaches a value and sent to controller. And based on that value, jsp is validated and accordingly forwarded. I tried submitting the form. Now the javascript function is getting called but it's not reaching upto controller.
My javascript function is like:
function navigate(){
  document.getElementById('idComeBackPage').value = '1';
  alert("In navigate");
  document.ouverture-form.submit();
 }

Comment: `document.getElementById('ouverture-form').submit();` Or `.forms['ouverture-form']`. That `-` is minus in JS.